# PHP / Unix - Unable to write to a file (permission denied - fopen)

Tags: php, unix, permissions, fopen

I have a simple problem that has me confused. I'm trying to write to a file using PHP fopen but I'm getting the error

```
"Warning: fopen(/var/www/********/file.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/********/index.php on line 339
```

The file (and directory) that I am trying to write to (file.php) has 777 permissions and is chowned to same user as index.php.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Is the file system using 64-bit inodes?

Comment: could it be the file is already opened in some other proces/editor ?

Comment: do you see any messages on screen or in log files about open_basedir ?

Comment: It's likely that the user running apache or whatever webserver you're using doesn't have write permissions to the path you're trying to write to.

Comment: I actually discovered that the problem was related to SELinux. I'm not really sure how SELinux works but by running the command "setenforce permissive", my problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to SELinux. I needed to run the following command:

```
setenforce permissive
```

Files are now writeable without issue.